# Can I compare 2 models by t-testing on the f-score?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, statistical-significance, cross-validation

In the neural network project, I used hold-out validation, repeated the experiment 10 times on the test set, and got 10 f-scores. Then experimented the baseline method 10 times too, and get another 10 f-scores. Can I do the t-test on 2 groups of f-scores and say that my technique is statistically better?

Additional description: I didn't use k-fold cross-validation, I just used hold-out. In order to eliminate the influence of the randomness of the neural network model, I repeated the experiment 10 times. I saw many papers that only report average f-score. Since the difference between the average f-score is not obvious, I did a t-test on them. The problem is that I don’t know if this approach makes sense, or like other papers, just report the average value is OK?

Additional description:  I first divide the data set into train and test with a ratio of 80:20. After training on the training set, use the results of the test set to calculate the f-value. Then I repeated the training and testing 10 times and got 10 f-values (the same dataset for each experiment).

Additional description: Since the initial weights of the neural network model may cause different results, so I retrain the model from scratch 10 times using different random weights, and then calculate the results on the test set.

Comment: Do you mean 10-fold cross validation? Probably no matter what you mean, you will have issues with dependence if you use a vanilla t-test. [Benavoli’s *Time for a Change* paper has some ideas.](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume18/16-305/16-305.pdf) // F1 score is a discontinuous, improper scoring rule. [Why not assess the probability outputs?](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/)

Comment: No, I didn't use k-fold cross-validation, I just used hold-out. In order to eliminate the influence of the randomness of the neural network model, I repeated the experiment 10 times. I saw many papers that only report average f-score. Since the difference between the average f-score is not obvious, I did a t-test on them. The problem is that I don’t know if this approach makes sense, or like other papers, just report the average value.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something a bit non-standard. Please give more details about your work.

Comment: @Dave Really simple way I did that. I first divide the data set into train and test with a ratio of 80:20. After training on the training set, use the results of the test set to calculate the f-value. Then I repeated the training and testing 10 times and got 10 f-values. The same process for baseline, repeat training and testing 10 times to get 10 f-values. Isn't this approach standard? Your opinion helped me a lot.

Comment: What do you mean that you repeated training and testing ten times?

Comment: @Dave Since the initial weights of the neural network model may cause different results, so I retrain the model from scratch every time using different random weights, and then calculate the results on the test set.